# Running a specific code once at 1st run Android

Tags: android

I want to run a code once the application run 1st time after installation. never again how to do it

following is the code here is how i am trying

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SecurityPrefs.setAutoSavePattern(this, true);

    String settingsTAG = "AppNameSettings";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(settingsTAG, 0);
    boolean run = prefs.getBoolean("run", false);

    if (run == false)
    {
        run = true;
    Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN, null,
            this, LockPatternActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CREATE_PATTERN);


    }
    else
    { Intent intent1 = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN,null,this,LockPatternActivity.class);

    startActivityForResult(intent1, REQ_ENTER_PATTERN);
    }


}
```

Comment: where do you save boolean?

Comment: i think in sharedpreferences

Comment: no, I mean you have to put something in sharedpreferences before you can get it, check vigbyor answer it is the right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what is the problem you are facing?

```
String settingsTAG = "AppNameSettings";
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(settingsTAG, 0);
boolean run = prefs.getBoolean("run", false);
```

Your code should work if after running for the first time you have updated the shared preference and stored true for "run".

Comment: it will work only if you update the value of "run" after first run. Vibgyor's code will work. Do that. 
`SharedPreferences.Editor editPrefs = prefs.edit();  
 editPrefs.putBoolean ( "run", true );
 editPrefs.commit();`

Comment: let me do it hangon :-p

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code as follows,

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SecurityPrefs.setAutoSavePattern(this, true);

        String settingsTAG = "AppNameSettings";
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(settingsTAG, 0);
        boolean run = prefs.getBoolean("run", false);

        if (run == true)
        {

        Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN, null,
                this, LockPatternActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CREATE_PATTERN);
        }
        else
        {
           SharedPreferences.Editor editPrefs = prefs.edit();  
           editPrefs.putBoolean ( "run", true );
           editPrefs.commit();          
           Intent intent1 = new       Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN,null,this,LockPatternActivity.class);

        startActivityForResult(intent1, REQ_ENTER_PATTERN);
        }
    }
```

After first run you need to set run's value to `true` in sharedpreference in else part.